# Celery - Django - 'null value in column "result" violates not-null constraint'

Tags: django, null, constraints, celery

I'm working on a django project using celery to queue differents tasks. Mostly we use it for mail sending, and we have plenty of tasks that are currently working under the same method. The things is that I'm having an error on production because suddenly celery doesn't save any values on the result field of the Task model. Hope this info is enough, if not, please ask. This is the traceback:

```
Task users.tasks.send_reset_password_task with id cf6ddab4-4407-477e-80e5-a5e50fbe4a90 raised exception:
'IntegrityError(\'null value in column "result" violates not-null constraint\\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (524, 2018-09-10 13:26:13.528034+00, {"errors": [{"error_code": 0, "error_data": {"user_id": 3298, "e..., 3298, 59, null, null).\\n\',)'


Task was called with args: [272, [3298]] kwargs: {u'_schema_name': u'tgs'}.

The contents of the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/users/tasks.py", line 618, in send_reset_password_task
    log_event(user=user, event_type=EventLogTypes.RESET_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SENT, success=success, extra={'errors': errors})
  File "/app/lmsplatform/services_eventlog.py", line 937, in log_event
    campaign_id=campaign_id,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: null value in column "result" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (524, 2018-09-10 13:26:13.528034+00, {"errors": [{"error_code": 0, "error_data": {"user_id": 3298, "e..., 3298, 59, null, null).
```

When running this task:

```
@app.task
def send_reset_password_task(tenant_id, users):
    tenant = Service.get_tenant_by_id(tenant_id)
    tenant_config = Service.get_tenant_config(tenant)
    message_list = []
    errors = []
    success = None
    mail_connection = Service.create_mail_connection()

    with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
        for user_id in users:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

            # Only if authentication method is PLATFORM or not PLATFORM and user is staff
            if tenant_config.users_authentication_method == 'PLATFORM' or (tenant_config.users_authentication_method != 'PLATFORM' and user.is_staff):
                tenant_domain = Service.get_tenant_domain(tenant.schema_name, protocol='https')

                uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
                token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)

                # Activate the language for this thread only
                translation.activate(user.userprofile.get_default_language())

                # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
                from_email = '%s <%s>' % (tenant.name, 'info@email.com')
                subject = _(u'%(first_name)s Recupera tu contraseña') % {'first_name': user.first_name}

                content_html = SimpleTemplateResponse("emails/reset_password.html", {
                    'user_name': user.username,
                    'user_first_name': user.first_name,
                    'tenant_domain': tenant_domain,
                    'uid': uid,
                    'token': token,
                    'tenant': tenant,
                    'lang': user.userprofile.get_default_language(),
                }, content_type="text/html", charset="utf-8").render().content

                msg = mail.EmailMessage(subject, content_html, from_email, [user.email], connection=mail_connection)
                msg.content_subtype = 'html'
                message_list.append(msg)

    try:
        mail_connection.open()
        success = mail_connection.send_messages([msg])
    except Exception as e:
        error = {'error_code': ErrorCodes.GENERAL_ERROR, 'error_data': {'user_id': user.id, 'error_detail': e.message}}
        errors.append(error)

    # Log mail result
    with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
        log_event(user=user, event_type=EventLogTypes.RESET_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SENT, success=success, extra={'errors': errors})
```

This task worked properly and now I'm facing this error when running this.
I can't find where the error is, I understand that I'm not setting the result field on the task model, but that it's supposed to be made automatically by celery itself.

Comment: Log is clear：File "/app/users/tasks.py", line 618, in send_reset_password_task

Comment: Yes, the log is clear, but actually there's no error in that line.

Comment: you should label this line for other one.